# How to loop through a select and using the return value in an insert query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, loops

I'm creating a stored procedure in SQL server and want to achieve the following:

I have to look up all the ResourceID's (could be any number of resources) for a certain ClientID in the Resources table.
Then I have to insert a row in the Planning table for each ResourceID found.

So I'll have something like

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT ResourceID AS @ResourceID FROM Resources WHERE ClientID = @ClientID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Planning (ResourceID, Date)
    VALUES (@ResourceID, @Date)
NEXT
END
```

I have already found that using a cursor might be the way, but that doesn't lead me to anything usable

Comment: for future reference: anytime you find yourself looking for a loop or cursor in SQL Server (especially a cursor) there is almost always a better way.

Comment: To help you learn about those better ways:http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for loops:

```
INSERT INTO Planning (ResourceID, Date)
SELECT ResourceID, GETDATE()
FROM Resources 
WHERE ClientID = @ClientID
```

In general, good practice is to avoid loops/cursors in SQL. Use set based options whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a cursor.  Keep it set-based:

```
insert into planning (resourceid, date)
select resourceid, @SomeDate
from resources
where clientid = @ClientId
```